# Cannot resolve method SubscribeOn - RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2, reactivex

I am very new to RxJava, I am trying to make Retrofit calls using RxJava. When I write this code on SubscribeOn it says 'Cannot resolve method SubscribeOn(io.reactivex.scheduler)'.

Could you guide on where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks
R

getDemoData in the Presenter layer.

```
  void getDemoData(){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(apiInterface.getDemoData()
                //subscribeOn has the error.
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // "work" on io thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // "listen" on UIThread
                .map(new Function<IApiCalls, List<DemoJSONAPIData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<DemoJSONAPIData> apply(
                            @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final IApiCalls apiCalls)
                            throws Exception {
                        // we want to have the geonames and not the wrapper object
                        return apiCalls.getDemoData();
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Geoname>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(
                            @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull final List<Geoname> geonames)
                            throws Exception {
                        //display
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/posts")
    //Single<DemoJSONAPIData> getDemoData();
    Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> getDemoData();
}
```

IApiCalls

```
public interface IApiCalls {
    List<DemoJSONAPIData> getDemoData();
}
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL_TWO = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public  static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_TWO)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) 
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Edit

My Retrofit call which I want to implement using RxJava/rxAndroid

```
 @Override
    public List<DemoJSONAPIData> getDemoData() {
        try{
            demoJSONAPIDatas = new ArrayList<>();
            apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call = apiInterface.getDemoData();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DemoJSONAPIData>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call, Response<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> response) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                    demoJSONAPIDatas = response.body();
                    Log.d("demoJSONAPIDatas", demoJSONAPIDatas.toString());
                    for(DemoJSONAPIData demoJSONAPIData: demoJSONAPIDatas){
                        Log.d("UserId", demoJSONAPIData.getId());
                        Log.d("Title", demoJSONAPIData.getTitle());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<DemoJSONAPIData>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("error", "error");
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return demoJSONAPIDatas;
    }
```

Error when using Single.
[image]

Comment: Did you deliberately comment out the reactive API in `ApiInterface`: `//Single<DemoJSONAPIData> getDemoData();`?

Comment: Hi @akarnokd tried with Single but that did not work. I was not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @akarnokd I have edited my question, I have a getDemoData() which performs a retrofit call to get data. I want to convert it to Observable/Observer pattern so that I can return data

Comment: How did `Single` not work?

Comment: Perhaps you need `Single<List<DemoJSONAPIData>>`.

Comment: @akarnokd added an image with the error message.

Comment: The error message *clearly* states you have the wrong generic type with the `map` function. You try to map the `IApiCalls` interface instead of the `DemoJSONAPIData` class.

Comment: How you are converting `DemoJSONAPIData` to `Geoname`? Your `map` operator  returns `List<DemoJSONAPIData>` as per your code , but at the end you are subscribing to `List<Geoname>`

Answer (score 13):

Check your import for observable in ApiInterface. it should be import io.reactivex.Observable;

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me too. So when I go check my APIinterface, it has automatically imported the 'import android.database.Observable;' instead of 'import io.reactivex.Observable;'. When u change it to that all the errors were gone.

Comment: I really appreciate your help I had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably added the wrong package.

These mistakes : 
" import java.util.* " --- 
" import android.database.Observable "

Actually:

" import io.reactivex.Observable "

You can make the necessary changes in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just Import the following on the api interface

import rx.Observable;

and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

```
 api.test(test)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<BaseResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(BaseResponse response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

 Observable<BaseResponse> test(@Field("test") String isOnline);
```

import Observable from rx java.